# element.scrollLeft does not work some times

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following div in my html

```
<div id="screen"></div>
```

Using Javascript, I add and remove images to the div. The div's styles are set to overflow scroll. I'm using jquery's scrollLeft to move the image left or right when ever it is clicked.

```
$("#screen").scrollLeft(location);
```

Each image has a different location value, which is passed into the function. My problem is that some times it works, and some times it doesn't. So, for example:

```
previousLocation = 800;
$("#screen").scrollLeft(previousLocation);
```

This works most of the time. But sometimes, it completely ignores the 800 and sets the scrollLeft to 0, so my image didn't scroll. This happens in firefox. It has not happened in safari, chrome, or opera.

Below is a smaller version of the code that I wrote. My code is pretty much the same, except it has a lot more images in the roomParams array.

```
var previousLocation = 0;
var roomParams = [
    {roomName: 'galleryEnter', imageLocation: 'images/galleryEnter.png', scroll: 'scrollX', backLocation: 0, mapName: 'galleryEnterMap', mapArray: [
        {mapAlt:'Happy Family Cage', mapShape:'poly', mapCoords:'261,352,6,372,4,3,256,2', clickEvent:'changeRoom("happyFamilyCage");'},
        {mapAlt:'Mice Notice', mapShape:'poly', mapCoords:'21,404,162,392,166,449,27,462', clickEvent:'changeRoom("miceNotice");'},
        {mapAlt:'Happy Family Sign', mapShape:'poly', mapCoords:'181,392,255,385,255,439,183,445', clickEvent:'changeRoom("happyFamilySign");'},
        {mapAlt:'Happy Family Sign 2', mapShape:'poly', mapCoords:'290,279,360,271,360,313,291,326', clickEvent:'changeRoom("happyFamilySign2");'},
    ]},
    {roomName: 'happyFamilyCage', imageLocation: 'images/happyFamilyCage.png', buttonBack: 'changeRoom("galleryEnter");', backLocation: 0},
    {roomName: 'miceNotice', imageLocation: 'images/miceNotice.png', buttonBack: 'changeRoom("galleryEnter");', backLocation: 500},
    {roomName: 'happyFamilySign', imageLocation: 'images/happyFamilySign.png', buttonBack: 'changeRoom("galleryEnter");', backLocation: 675},
    {roomName: 'happyFamilySign2', imageLocation: 'images/happyFamilySign2.png', buttonBack: 'changeRoom("galleryEnter");', backLocation: 1000}
];

function changeRoom(setRoom){
    var element;
    var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
    var roomImage = document.createElement("img");
    var roomMap = document.createElement("map");
    var mapArea = document.createElement("area");
    $("#screen").empty(); //empty all content in screen div
    for(x=0; x < roomParams.length; x++){ //search the array until setRoom matches the roomName
        if(setRoom == roomParams[x].roomName){
            element = roomImage.cloneNode(true);
            element.setAttribute("src", roomParams[x].imageLocation);
            fragment.appendChild(element);
            document.getElementById("screen").appendChild(fragment);        
            if(roomParams[x].mapName){
                //if image has hotspots, create the map tag on html page
                element.setAttribute("usemap", "#" + roomParams[x].mapName);
                element = roomMap.cloneNode(true);
                element.setAttribute("name", roomParams[x].mapName);
                element.setAttribute("id", "currentMap");
                fragment.appendChild(element);
                document.getElementById("screen").appendChild(fragment);
                for(y=0; y < roomParams[x].mapArray.length; y++){
                    //adding multiple area tags to html page
                    element = mapArea.cloneNode(true);
                    element.setAttribute("href", "#");
                    element.setAttribute("alt", roomParams[x].mapArray[y].mapAlt);
                    element.setAttribute("shape", roomParams[x].mapArray[y].mapShape);
                    element.setAttribute("coords", roomParams[x].mapArray[y].mapCoords);
                    element.setAttribute("onclick", roomParams[x].mapArray[y].clickEvent);
                    fragment.appendChild(element);
                    document.getElementById("currentMap").appendChild(fragment);
                }
            }
            if(roomParams[x].scroll){
                //if image is larger than 640x480, set the scroll
                document.getElementById("screen").className = roomParams[x].scroll;
            }
            else{
                //else remove the scroll
                document.getElementById("screen").className = "scrollNone";
            }
            if(roomParams[x].buttonBack){
                //if there is a previous room before the image, activate back button
                element = document.getElementById("backButton");
                element.className = "";
                element.setAttribute("onclick", roomParams[x].buttonBack);
            }
            else{
                //else deactivate back button
                document.getElementById("backButton").className = "gray";
            }
            $("#screen").scrollLeft(previousLocation);
            previousLocation = roomParams[x].backLocation;
            break;
        }
    }
}

window.addEventListener("load", function(){
    changeRoom("galleryEnter");
});
```

Anyone can help me figure out what is wrong here? Is scrollLeft just buggy in firefox or something?

Comment: is something else on the page changing that could cause scrolling after you're calling `scrollLeft`? It looks like you're adding elements to the page that could be causing it to scroll

Comment: I don't think so.. I made sure to do the scrollLeft last just in case that happens, so I'm not sure. I'll look over it again just to be sure.

Comment: I also noticed that if I add an alert right before the element.scrollLeft, the problem stops and it works all of the time. I have no idea why this is happening.

Comment: this probably means that some other operation is running that doesn't complete until after `scrollLeft` been called, which is adjusting the page. try to figure out what the is, and add a handler for when that's done to `scrollLeft`